# D3js: drag slider working with touch

Tags: d3.js

I found a great example of d3.js drag slider https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6452972 However I can't use the drag feature using iOS10. How can I enable touch features to this slider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is interesting.  In that code, the *drag events" are set up on an invisible line painted on top of the slider.  Looks like iOS won't reliably honor the touch events on it because it is not stroked or filled.  You can get it to work though by changing the css definition on `.track-overlay` to:

```
.track-overlay {
  pointer-events: stroke;
  stroke-width: 50px;
  cursor: crosshair;
  stroke: black; /*<-- give it a stroke */
  opacity: 0; /*<-- but don't show it */ 
}
```